# How to install fonts for CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, fonts

Just learning, and trying to install a new font into my system.

So far, I have created a directory "fonts", and unzip "oregon" fonts into this folder. Now the fonts are in /home/denny/fonts.

How do I move these fonts to /usr/share/fonts? I have also created a new folder "oregon" in this fonts directory. I THINK all my default fonts are in this directory.

I know I am missing something here.

Thank you,
Denny

Comment: it should be `.fonts` note the `.`.

Comment: Can you please show me the steps? Sorry, a Linux newbie here. Thanks again for your time, and sorry for the trouble.  -Denny

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a folder in your `home` directory called `.fonts`:

```
mkdir /home/$USER/.fonts
```

Unzip the files and move them there. Now run the command from your terminal:

```
fc-cache -v
fc-cache-64 -v
```

And the font should be available now.

More info, see `man fc-cache`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       fc-cache scans the font directories on the system and builds font information cache files for applications  using  fontconfig
       for their font handling.

       If  directory  arguments  are  not  given,  fc-cache uses each directory in the current font configuration. Each directory is
       scanned for font files readable by FreeType. A cache is created which contains properties of each  font  and  the  associated
       filename.  This cache is used to speed up application startup when using the fontconfig library.

       Note that fc-cache must be executed once per architecture to generate font information customized for that architecture.
```